# Enable Driver Using Buildroot Menuconfig

Tags: buildroot

I have a Beaglebone Black (BBB), and I want to create a boot image for it using Buildroot.  In Buildroot, I created a .config file using `make beaglebone_defconfig`.  Then I run `make menuconfig`, since I want to add a driver to the build.  I cannot find any place in the menu to add a driver. In particular, I want to add the ADAU1761 audio codec driver.  Is there any way to do this from menuconfig in Buildroot?  If not, what are my alternatives (assuming I want to stick with Buildroot as my build tool)?  I realize I also have to modify the device tree to add the codec, but at the moment I'm just trying to enable the codec driver to make sure it is part of the build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make menuconfig` allows to tweak the Buildroot configuration, not the Linux kernel configuration. To tweak the Linux kernel configuration, run `make linux-menuconfig`, which will fire up the menuconfig of the Linux kernel.

See https://bootlin.com/doc/training/buildroot/buildroot-slides.pdf starting slide 76 for more details on the Linux kernel configuration.